# How do i get random Cross Sell Products?

Tags: cross-sells, random

This is the piece of code that generates the cross products:

```
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
<?php 
    $_product = $this->getProduct(); 
   // echo get_class($this); 
?>

<?php if($_crossSellProducts = $_product->getCrossSellProducts()): ?>

    <div class="crosssell">
        <h2><?php echo $this->__('Suntem mandri sa va prezentam clientii TRENDfurniture:') ?></h2>

        <ul id="crosssell-products-list">
        <?php foreach ($_crossSellProducts as $_item): ?>

            <?php  
            $_item = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId()); 
            ?>
            <li class="item">
                <a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail'); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" />
                </a>
            </li>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>

        <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('crosssell-products-list', 'none-recursive')</script>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

I tried to use:

```
 $_item ->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));                  
 $_item ->setPage(1, 4);
```

but with no result.This is the result of the **get_class** function : **Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View**

Comment: Side note - loading products one by one inside the loop is not a good practice.

Comment: @Amasty I inherited it, I just want to display it randomly and put a limit. is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a function on view.php

```
    public function getCrosspro(){
        $product = $this->getProduct();
        /* @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */

        $itemCollection = $product->getCrossSellProductCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
            ->setPositionOrder()
            ->addStoreFilter();

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($itemCollection);
            $itemCollection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()')); 
            $itemCollection->setPage(1, 4);
         $itemCollection->load();

        foreach ($itemCollection as $product) {
            $product->setDoNotUseCategoryId(true);
        };

return $itemCollection
}
```

and  change:

```
<?php if($_crossSellProducts = $_product->getCrossSellProducts()): ?>
```

to

```
<?php if($_crossSellProducts = $this->getCrosspro()): ?>
```

Comment: woaw, you saved my day, but can you give me more explanation to understand what does function exacty do ? thx a lot

Comment: Ya I will reply shortly

Answer (score 2):

To implement custom logic for cross sell products, you can override the  method getCrossSellProducts or call a method from your own class where do all the magic.

If you need just use the default logic, but sort products randomly each time you need to add sorting by rand **before** the collection is loaded, not after, as it has no effect.

Edit: 
Based on your code, apply sorting and limitation on `$_crossSellProducts` before the loop.

Comment: You could also override `getCrossSellProductCollection()`, which is called by `getCrossSellProducts()` - just another option.

Comment: Your suggestion to apply sorting and limitation on `$_crossSellProducts` won't work, because `getCrossSellProducts()` returns an array of products, not an actual collection.

Comment: @Colin Thanks for the correction, not at the pc now and my memory servers me bad (

Answer (score 1):

The cross-sell product collection can be obtained using this code:

```
$_crossSellProductCollection = $_product->getCrossSellProductCollection();
```

You'd then use that to set the random order and page size:

```
$_crossSellProductCollection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
$_crossSellProductCollection->setPage(1, 4);
```

**Edit:** You can then iterate over those products like so:

```
<?php foreach ($_crossSellProductCollection as $_item): ?>
    ...
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: and this should i include where ?

Comment: im getting this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function getSelect() on a non-object .....

Comment: You can include this in your template file.